# How to make an armoured zombie filter?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to make an **armour farm** using a zombie Mob Spawner (found in a dungeon) and I want to filter zombies which have **diamond armour** (iron would also do) from unarmoured ones, killing those without armor on the way to a room where I can safely kill those who have some. So far, I tried using **small lava channels**, but they move too slow in them and die.
**Any help for separating armoured zombies from unarmoured ones?**

Comment: Are you able to use commands?

Comment: I don't want to use commands for it. @WillB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an Armour Filter Farm example:

1. Here is the main redstone mechanism composed of tripwire, wire, redstone repeaters with delay level 4 and a sticky piston attached to a slime block, that pushes the burning zombies out of the fire.
   [image: The redstone mechanism]
2. This is the spawning platform, which must let zombies pass only through the hole.
   [image: The platform]
3. This is the push-down-into-fire mechanism, that uses tripwire for powering and a villager "helper" to attract zombies into it.
   [image: The pusher]
4. This is how the mechanism looks from above.
   [image: Above Look]
5. Here is the villager "helper" that attracts zombies.
   [image: The villager]
6. This is the Zombie that burns and is about to be pushed out of fire by a slime block into a hole.
   [image: Burning zombie]
7. This Zombie was unarmoured, so he died while on fire because the water didn't had time to extinguish him.
   [image: Dying Zombie]
8. This is the extinguishing system, that uses water to extinguish zombies with an armour level of at least 3 out of 20. The water is blocked by a piston while there is no entity inside the trap. It uses tripwire, linked by wire to a Redstone Torch (NOT Gate) that reverses redstone signal ("powered" becomes "unpowered" and "unpowered" becomes "powered") linked to the piston by wire. Also, the rotten flesh doesn't go to a waste; instead it is collected by hoppers and sent into a chest.
   [image: Redstone mechanism]

   9. Now another zombie that unlike the other, has a Diamond Helmet, burns in the hole…
      [image: Armoured burning zombie]
      …but unlike the other, he **didn't die** and the water saved him in time!
      [image: Fire survival]

**So this farm is effective for zombies wearing at least a diamond helmet.**
Note that it may not work on baby zombies and, also, multiple zombies "using" it may corrupt the mechanism, so you can add walls at the spawner or a redstone mechanism that allows a single zombie to pass in a certain number of seconds, for example

Comment: Sorry for spamming photos on Imgur for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should make a standard zombie crusher. The armoured zombies won't die and can after the crushing be transported somewhere else using a water stream. You'll need a bit of redstone knowledge and a [zombie crusher design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a88ctQeEqTk). Almost any design on YouTube will do just fine.

Comment: I already did one, thanks. I wanted to post a self-answer as a video, but I had problems uploading.